# How to find GPU memory(video memory) using NVAPI

Tags: memory, video, nvapi

I am using NVAPI, I can get some performance data by calling this function:

```
NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx
```

But don't know how to get video memory usage. I find [some c# codes](http://open-hardware-monitor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Hardware/Nvidia/NvidiaGPU.cs) call this function to get it.

```
NVAPI.NvAPI_GPU_GetMemoryInfo
```

But there is no the same function in NVAPI.

Any idea?

Comment: that C# code does use nvapi.dll, GetDelegate(0x774AA982, out NvAPI_GPU_GetMemoryInfo);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be in NVAPI?  If not, check out Nvidia PerfKit:  http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody still needs this, you can use this library:

https://github.com/falahati/NvAPIWrapper

---

1. Find the right GPU using the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.GetPhysicalGPUs()` static method.
2. Use the `NvAPIWrapper.GPU.PhysicalGPU.MemoryInfo` property to get the total memory, available memory and other information relative to memory.

Comment: I think for what OP asked you are using NvAPI_GPU_GetPhysicalFrameBufferSize (which is call from nvapi if somebody need it) if I checked the repo properly...